# Frontend not working after magento upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-upgrade

I have upgrade magento version from 2.1.14 to 2.2.9.

Admin panel is working properly but frontend not working.

Showing this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'arguments': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 840
```

I have run upgrade, compile, deploy command. I have also try to change mode but still frontend not working.

> debug.log showing this

```
[2019-07-11 10:09:22] report.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_464f7cbd6294e40256ecc52fd4711dd60_page_layout_merged and handles default, cms_noroute_index, cms_page_view, cms_noroute_index_id_no-route: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'arguments': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 840
 [] []
[2019-07-11 10:09:22] report.ERROR: Element 'arguments': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( argument ).
Line: 840
 [] []
```

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank You.

Comment: Any error log or console log evident?

Comment: not getting any hint from log, it's showing default report log entry

Comment: Okay, do you get any errors in the browser console? Is the entire page broken, try changing theme to magento luma theme and check if it works fine

Comment: did you `cache:flush` ?

Comment: yes, i have flush cache.

Comment: The 3rd Party Modules and Themes have the issue in UI component XML files. It is really difficult to find which one, try disabling modules and themes.

Comment: please look at this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231269/magento-2-element-file-this-element-is-not-expected

Comment: @MilindSingh, i have set default luma theme from admin and also disable custom module but not luck

Comment: @RajMohanR, i have set default luma theme from admin and also disable custom module but not luck

Comment: So you have disabled the third party modules too right. Can you please let me know what error are you getting in the browser console

Comment: still showing same error as i have describe in above question

Comment: Can you please try removing all static files such as var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed var/di pub/static/frontend generated/* and run the upgrade, compile and deploy commands. Else have you tried this before

Comment: @RajMohanR, removed cache,pub,generation but not working. showing same error.